# C++ for loop array assignment. Getting junk returned

Tags: c++

I'm trying to generate LIMIT (lets say limit = 1000) prime numbers and store them to an array, but I get junk returned. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void prime_num(int);
int main()
{
    int primes[1000];
    int n, p, t, LIMIT = 1000;
    for(n=2; n <= LIMIT; n++)
    {
        t=0;
        for(p=2; p <= n/2; p++)
        {
            if (n%p == 0)
            {
                t = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!t) 
            primes[p-2] = n;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++)
        cout << primes[i] <<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd start by breaking it up into some understandable pieces. You seem to have had that in mind with the prototype for `prime_num`, but don't seem to have followed through. I'd also change that to something like `bool isprime(int);` that returns a bool to indicate whether a particular number is prime.

Comment: I think you want to find primes less than or equal to LIMIT; not find LIMIT primes.

Answer (score 5):

Define a variable outside the outer loop:

```
int count=0;
```

and then use it here:

```
primes[count++] = n;
```

then print as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    cout << primes[i] <<" ";
```

**Explanation:**

You're not generating `1000` prime numbers, rather you're generating all prime numbers less than or equal to `1000`.

---

As @Jerry Coffin commented, your code should be like this:

<sup>Note : I'm not  talking about *correctness*, rather the *skeleton* of the program; so you decide if `is_prime()` function is correct or not, optimized or not, etc.</sup>

```
bool  is_prime(int n)
{
        for(int p=2; p <= n/2; p++)
        {
            if (n%p == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
int main()
{
    int primes[1000];
    int n, p, t, LIMIT = 1000;
    int count=0;
    for(n=2; n <= LIMIT; n++)
    {
       if (is_prime(n) )
          primes[count++] = n;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        cout << primes[i] <<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

**Correctness and Optimization of `is_prime()`:**

Now you decide the correctness of `is_prime()`. Is it correctly written? Is it optimized? Do you really need to check for all integers in the range `[2,n/2]`?

Comment: And in your final loop, `i < count` instead of `i < LIMIT`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a more compact way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @user1293973: Think and Try Yourself. :-)